# Вывод фотографий в модальном окне

Tags: php, mysql

На странице выводятся фотографии и мне надо, чтоб при нажатии фотографии он открывал именно ту фотографию на которую нажал, и чтоб в ссылке показываться id фотографии, чтобы можно было перейти по ссылке на фотографию.

Сейчас у меня такой код, но он не выводит ту самую фотографию на которую я нажал.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id='$_GET[id]'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    while ($useridphoto = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
    ?> // Вывод id в url
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE useridphoto='$useridphoto[id]' LIMIT 0,10") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    while ($photo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
        echo "<a href='#photo?id=$useridphoto[id]' style='margin-left: 10px;'><img src='$photo[photo]?id=$useridphoto[id]' width='60' height='60' style='
        border-radius: 4px;
        moz-border-radius: 4px;
        webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        '></a>"; // и выводим их на страницу
    }
}
?> // Вывод фотографий на странице

<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="photo?id=<?php echo $useridphoto[id]; ?>"></a>
        <div class="popup">

                   <?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE useridphoto='$useridphoto[id]' LIMIT 0,1") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
if($result) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    while ($photoclick = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
        echo "<img src='$photoclick[photo]?id=$useridphoto[id]' width='100' height='100'>"; // и выводим их на страницу
    }
}

 ?>

        <a class="close"title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
            <?php
    }
}

 ?> // Вывод фотографий в модальном окне
```

Comment: `?> // Вывод фотографий на странице`

 так комменты ставить нельзя в php

Comment: Так и хочется отдать что нибудь подобное:
 
    you_gate.php?id=%27%3B%20DROP%20DATABASE%20mysql%3B%20SELECT%20SLEEP(999)%3B

Comment: если вы про комментарий Олега Б, то это sql-инъекция

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внедрение_SQL-кода

перед использованием любых данных, получаемых от пользователя, необходимо их проверять/фильтровать